# Can anyone provide me all the verses of Buddha and their translations in the puranas?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, avatars, identification-request

From wikipedia, I found Lord Buddha who is said to be the ninth avatara of Vishnu to be mentioned in the following texts:

- Harivamsa (1.41)
- Vishnu Purana (3.18)
- Bhagavata Purana (1.3.24, 2.7.37, 11.4.23)
- Garuda Purana (1.1, 2.30.37, 3.15.26)
- Agni Purana (16)
- Naradiya Purana (2.72)
- Linga Purana (2.71)
- Padma Purana (3.252)

Can anyone provide me the above verses and their translations from the above texts?

Comment: You can get few such Puranic verses on this page: https://www.kamakotimandali.com/misc/buddha-purana.html

Comment: Indianscriptures.com has all Puranas in Sanskrit and English. Check [What are some online sources to get unabridged Hindu Scriptures or to learn Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15424/3500)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am only providing Sanskrit verses from four  Puranas Garuda purana , Harivamsha Purana , Shreemad Bhagvatam and vishnu purana.

So consider this as partial answer

**Harivamsha Purana 1.41.164**

> कल्किर्विष्णुयशा नाम् शम्भले ग्रामके दविज : | 
>  सर्वलोकहितार्थाय
>   भुयच्श्रयोत्पत्स्यते प्रभु || 164||
>
> **In the future avataras Buddha will appear first** , then there will be a
>   famous avatara called “Kalki”     also will be known as “VishnuShaya”
>   .Lord Vishnu will appear as brahamna in “Shammal” village for welfare
>   of this universe.

---

**Shreemad Bhagavata purana १.३.२४**

> तत: कलौ संप्रवृत्ते सम्मोहाय सुरद्विषाम् | 
>  बुद्धो नाम्नाजनसुत:
>   कीकटेषु भविष्यति ||१.३.२४||
>
> tataḥ kalau sampravṛtte sammohāya sura-dviṣām 
>  Budho
>   nāmnāñjana-sutaḥ kīkaṭeṣu bhaviṣyati
>
> **Then, in the beginning of Kali-yuga, the Lord will appear as Lord
>   Buddha,** the son of Añjanā, in the province of Gayā, just for the
>   purpose of deluding those who are envious of the faithful theist.
>   [**SB 1.3.34**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/24)
>
> ---
>
> देवद्विषाम निगमवर्त्मनि निष्ठितानां | 
>  पूर्भिर्मयेन
>   विहिताभिरदृश्यतुर्भि:| 
>  लोकान घ्रतां मतिविमोहमतिप्रलोभं ||
>   वेषं विधाय बहु भाष्यत औपधर्म्यम् ||३७||
>
> deva-dviṣāṁ nigama-vartmani niṣṭhitānāṁ pūrbhir mayena vihitābhir
>   adṛśya-tūrbhiḥ  lokān ghnatāṁ mati-vimoham atipralobhaṁ veṣaṁ vidhāya
>   bahu bhāṣyata aupadharmyam
>
> When the atheists, after being well versed in the Vedic scientific
>   knowledge, annihilate inhabitants of different planets, flying unseen
>   in the sky on well-built rockets prepared by the great scientist Maya,
>   the **Lord will bewilder their minds by dressing Himself attractively as
>   Buddha** and will preach on subreligious principles.
>   [**SB 2.7.37**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/7/37)
>
> ---
>
> भूमेर्भरावतरणाय यदुष्वजन्मा | 
>  जात: करिष्यति सुरैरपि दुष्कराणि||
>   
>  वादैर्विमोहयति यज्ञकृतोsतदर्हान् | 
>  शूद्रान् कलौ क्षितिभुजो
>   न्यहनिष्यदन्ते ||
>
> bhūmer bharāvataraṇāya yaduṣv ajanmā 
> jātaḥ kariṣyati surair api
>   duṣkarāṇi  vādair vimohayati yajña-kṛto ’tad-arhān
>  śūdrān kalau
>   kṣiti-bhujo nyahaniṣyad ante
>
> To diminish the burden of the earth, the unborn Lord will take birth
>   in the Yadu dynasty and perform feats impossible even for the
>   demigods. **Propounding speculative philosophy, the Lord, as Buddha**,
>   will bewilder the unworthy performers of Vedic sacrifices. And as
>   Kalki the Lord will kill all the low-class men posing as rulers at the
>   end of the Age of Kali.[**SB 11.4.22**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/4/22)
>
> ---

**Garuda Purana  , Brahma Moksha Kanda , Chapter 15**

> तत: कलौ संप्रवृत्ते हार्रिस्तु | 
>  संमोहनार्थं चासुरणां खगेन्द्र ||
>   
>  नाम्ना बुद्धो कीकटेषु प्रजातो |
>  वेदप्रमाणम निराकर्तुमेव
>   ||२६||  GP 3.15.26 ||
>
> Then in the Kali age , **the lord was born in Kikatas as Buddha**.He
>   deluded the asuras  and flouted the Vedas.
>
> ---

**Garuda Purana , Preta Kanda , Chapter 30**

> मत्स्यं कर्म्मं च वाराहं नारसिंहस्च्र वामनं | 
>  रामं रामं च कृष्णं
>   च बुद्धं चैव सकल्किनं |
>  एतानि दशे नामानि स्मर्त्यव्यानि सदा बुधै
>   ||३७||  GP 2.30.37
>
> The names of ten incarnations of the lord viz.  Matsya (fish) , Kurma
>   (tortoise) , Varaha (boar) , Narasihmha , Srirama , Parashu-rama ,
>   Krishna ,**Buddha** and Kalki shall remembered always.
>
> ---

**Vishnu Purana - Book 3 - Chapter 18 verse 18,19,20**

> एवं बुध्यत बुध्यत्वं बुध्यतैवमितिरयन |
>  मायामोह: स दैतेयान्
>   धर्ममत्याजयन्निजम् || १८ || 
>  नानाप्रकारवचनं स तेषां युक्तियोजितम्
>   |
>  तथा तथा च तध्दर्मं तत्यजुस्ते यथा यथा || १९||
>  तेsप्यन्येषान
>   तथैवोचुन्यैरन्ये तथोदिता : |
>  मैत्रैय ! तत्यजुर्धर्मं
>   वेद   स्मृत्युदितं परम् ||२०||
>
> Parasara said – In this manner , exclaiming to them , “Know”
>   (Budhyadvam) and they replying “It is known”( Budhyati) , these
>   Daityas were induced by the arch deceiver to deviate from their
>   **religious deities (and become Buddhas)**, by his repeated arguments and
>   variously urged persuasion’s. When they abandoned  their own faith ,
>   they persuaded  others to do the same and the heresy spread and any
>   deserted the practices enjoined by the Vedas and the Laws.

Correction required -  It’s the verse no 11.4.22 and not the 23 of Bhagvata Purana as stated by you in question.

[image]

---

[image]

**Note – I will update the answer with verses from other puranas very soon.**

Comment: Is kikatas old name for Gaya?

Comment: @Ajay See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kikata_Kingdom