# Do Nastika and Astika have direct translations in English?

Tags: philosophy, sanskrit

We have a gross translation of `Astika` and `Nastika` as theism and Atheism. However, the etymology of `Nastika` (`na-asti-ka`) seems to indicate 'someone who does not believe in what exists`.

Is there an accurate translation of the words in English ?

Also, what do they exactly mean as per Hindu scriptures ? I know of Charvaka and his Nastika theories, but is that the only one ?

Comment: This question is not equivalent to the question What is the relationship between Hinduism and Atheism? I request the moderatos to reopen this question so that I can answer this question based on the original sources. I have a pertinent answer.

Comment: @user Read the answers written to the question linked. Only the title of that question is written that way but the question asks definition of Nastika and Astika. The OP themselves was satisfied with the closure. If you have answer to this question, post it in the original question.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I think it's okay to have similar answers to different questions. Particularly since people will come across Q&As from search engines and the question wording is what catches peoples' eyes

Comment: I do think this question might be better for Sanskrit.SE proposal at https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123261/sanskrit-language without clarification it's hard to know

Comment: When the question was created, it was to know a direct translation of a term in sanatana dharma into English. This was definitely not meant to be a Sanskrit.SE question.