# Is following atheistic like Samkhya wrong, according to manu Smriti?

Tags: manu-smriti, atheism

Manu Smriti 11.66

> 11.66. Stealing grain, base metals, or cattle, intercourse with women who drink spirituous liquor, slaying women, Sudras, Vaisyas, or Kshatriyas, and **atheism**, (are all) minor offences, causing loss of caste (Upapataka).

So if someone becomes an atheist he will loss his cast.

But Samkhya school of thought is a atheist school. They believe in God.

If a person is following Samkhya school will he lose his cast. Or will he be committing minor.

---

<sup>The [source](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/45280/22556) of this verse is a question I found on this website.</sup>

Comment: Atheism is defined as non belief in vedas. All six schools of hinduism believe in vedas. Some say authorless, non-eternal, some say otherwise but all six schools believe in the validity of vedas.

Comment: @GIRIBLR Atheism, in the broadest sense, is an absence of belief in the existence of deities. Less broadly, atheism is a rejection of the belief that any deities exist.

Comment: @GIRIBLR so atheistism means no God

Comment: That's the modern definition. In sanatana dharma, atheism means not belief in Vedas. Like jains and buddhism. Mimansa also does not believe in ishvara, but is a school of sanatana dharma. All six schools and subschools believe in vedas. That's the definition to be included in sanatana dharma.

Comment: @GIRIBLR okay thanks for it

Comment: @GIRIBLR Astika/Nastika don't mean faith/no-faith in Vedas. If that's the meaning then that's unnaturally derived one. Those who don't believe in existence of divinity, after life are Nastika and the opposite of that is Astika. See this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37187/4732

Comment: Manu Smriti is not condemning Samkhya at all. See the link I gave above to understand which kind of people Manu is condemning. Its the Charvaks and similar type of people who don't believe in the existence of after life, divinity, divine justice/punishment etc @DarkKnight

Comment: you are misinterpreting the Samkhya philosophy and also conflating it with Manu smriti. The Samkhya school was a philosophical school, whereas the Manu Smriti is a guide to daily life. Read the first two pages of Chapter 9 on Samkhya here - https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manu Smriti verse correct translation goes like this

> Stealing grain, base metals and cattle,—intercourse with women
> addicted to drinking wine,—killing women, Śūdras, Vaiśyas and
> Kṣatriyas,—and **heresy**,—everyone of these is a **‘minor
> offence.’**(Manu 11.66)

Commentary of Medhatithi reads

> Heresy— the holding of such opinions as **‘there is no heaven,—there
> is no virtue in charity’** and so forth.

According to Manu Smriti, Atheism/Heresy means lack of faith in Vedas.

> He shall, **avoid atheism**, cavilling at the Vedas, abusing of the gods,
> hatred, haughtiness, pride, anger and hastiness.(Manu 4.163)

Commentary of Medhatithi reads

> ‘Atheism’ consists in **thinking, as untrue, of things that are spoken
> of in the Veda.**

Since Samkhya accepts authority of Vedas, following Samkhya isn't bad. Also Gita says

> Of all trees I am the holy fig tree, and amongst sages and demigods I
> am Narada. Of the singers of the gods I am Citraratha, and **among
> perfected beings I am the sage Kapila**.(BG 10.26)

Comment: So people who reject vedas are atheist(according to manu Smriti), so Christians are also atheist according to manu Smriti.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Dark knight if belief in God is required for astika, mimansa will become nastika. If belief in after life is only required, then Buddhism will become astika. But we know mimansa is astika and Buddhism is nastika. So setu answer is correct. It is a great answer.

Comment: @DarkKnight Probably not. Those statements of Manu were written to denounce guys who don't believe in Vedas. Or encourage belief in Vedas. Christians don't know Vedas to denounce it. We have a Skanda Purana verse saying all religions read to truth. I think you remember it