# Buddha avatar of Vishnu

Tags: vishnu, avatars

Between Krishna and Kalki avatars there is Buddha/Boudha avatara. Is this Gautama Buddha? 
Related, why Vishnu coming as Mohini is not considered one of Dashavatara?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Gautama Buddha an avatar of Lord Vishnu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/180/is-gautama-buddha-an-avatar-of-lord-vishnu)

Comment: the Buddha part has been asked and answered.  Perhaps why Mohini is not considered one of the 10 avatars can be a separate question.

Comment: There is nothing called Dashavatara. Lord Vishnu has taken more than 10 avatars. In no scripture has it been mentioned that Lord Vishnu will taken 10 and only 10 avatars

Comment: @Carmensandiego, there definitely is something called Dashavatara, and definitely are scriptural references to the same. You can inquire further on this site if interested. It is also true that his avataras are not limited to 10. These 2 things are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @ram - True. I did see the term in Garuda Purana. What I meant is that the term has been reduced to imply that Lord Vishnu will take only 10 avatars.

Comment: @Carmensandiego, yes, that is the opinion held by majority of people who are still new to intricacies of Hinduism. I was of the same opinion until I learned about 24 avataras in Bhagavatam. Then I was of *that* opinion, until I learned his avataras are infinite. Each person is at a different stage of learning. While showing someone to a higher truth, we don't need to say that the old truth was a lie. It was a smaller truth.

Comment: @ram what do you mean by infinite avataras?

Comment: @Wikash_, his avataras are not limited to 10 or 24, he takes as many as and when he wants to fulfill desires of him/devotees. avatara means to descend - he could descend for 2 minutes, give darshan to devotee and get back before anyone notices.

Comment: @ram where did you find this in the scriptures?

Comment: @Wikash_, Purusha Sooktam clearly mentions it. 'The unborn takes very many births'

Comment: @ram Very many is not infinite.

Comment: @Wikash_, bahudha is the exact term. no number is mentioned. also the entire universe is cylic, and He promises to descend every Yuga when dharma declines, so it's obvious we can't put an upper limit to His number of avataras