# Who/What were the sources that Valmiki referred to when compiling his Ramayan

Tags: ramayana

Valmiki was not a contemporary of Ram. So who or what were his sources.

Comment: Valmiki is contemporary of Lord Rama, see my answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17528/between-da%c5%9baratha-j%c4%81taka-and-v%c4%81lm%c4%abki-r%c4%81m%c4%81ya%e1%b9%87a-which-is-older/17537#17537